# populate listbox from 2 textboxes

Tags: c#

How do you get the text from two textboxes to populate a listbox on a Windows Form Application? I can not get the text that is put into the textboxes to go to the listbox.

This is the code I got so far:

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("Contacts.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader Info = new StreamReader("Contacts.txt");
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            while (Info.EndOfStream != true)
                listBox1.Items.Add(Info.ReadLine());
            Info.Close();
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("/n");
    }
```

But that Console.WriteLine("/n");  does not put a space between the next entry of the textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Add()` with the `Text` property of the `TextBox` not the text box itself.  See below.

EDITED: Added way to add the `Text` to the `ListBox` and still clear the `TextBox` controls afterwards.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter Info = File.AppendText("Contacts.txt");

    string textbox1Content = textbox1.Text;
    string textbox1Content = textbox2.Text;


    listBox1.Items.Add(textbox1Content);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textbox1Content);

    textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    textBox2.Text = String.Empty;

}
```

Also I don't understand your `for` loop... it only executes one time.  Whats the point exactly?

Comment: How would you clear the textboxes after the button is pressed?
TextBox1.Clear

Comment: What loop would best be ran?  Or what should be put for the length

Comment: No loop at all is best. Also, `textBox1.Text = "";`

Comment: What you put in the TextBoxes is put in the listbox. Such as name and address. Once the button is pressed it will clear the textbox and populate the listbox. Now if you have 25 names and addresses to put in you want it to run as many times as you will have that data

Comment: Give us an example of what would be written in each textbox before the press, and what the listbox should look like after the button is pressed.

Comment: textbox1: Frank
textbox2: 123 maple dr.

In the list box it will show:
Frank
123 maple dr.

Comment: I also need to know a way to put a space between the contacts

Comment: I have edited my question to better answer what you are asking.  If you have more questions, either append your original question, read a tutorial, or ask another question.